# Expo react native cannot get rewarded admob to show in dev or build

Tags: javascript, react-native, admob

I have a code that runs admob as soon as the page loads like below

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const admobId = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? SETTINGS.ADMOB_IOS_AD_UNIT_ID : SETTINGS.ADMOB_ANDROID_AD_UNIT_ID;
    AdMobRewarded.setAdUnitID(admobId); // Test ID, Replace with your-admob-unit-id
    AdMobRewarded.addEventListener("rewardedVideoDidRewardUser", this.onRewarded);
    AdMobRewarded.addEventListener("rewardedVideoDidFailToLoad", this.videoFailedToLoad);

    await AdMobRewarded.requestAdAsync();
    await AdMobRewarded.showAdAsync();
}
```

However, when I try to run the ad, the ad fails with

> "name": "Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request Error: No ad to show.}",

I have checked my admob unit ID many times and made sure it is correct. Test version of admobId works (ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917) but my own doesn't.

I am currently using expo admob module. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you testing this on an emulator? If so you need to add AdMobRewarded.setTestDeviceID('EMULATOR');

Answer (score 0):

```
const unitIdrewared = ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712

await AdMobRewarded.setAdUnitID(unitIdrewared);
await AdMobRewarded.requestAdAsync();
await AdMobRewarded.showAdAsync();
```

steps:

right now am using 13 version of expo-ads-admob you can upgrade if needed

install "expo-ads-admob": "^13.0.0", >> npm i expo-ads-admob OR npx expo install expo-ads-admob

Example.,

```
import { AdMobRewarded } from "expo-ads-admob";

import { useEffect} from "react";

export const HomeScreen = (props) => {
 useEffect(() => {
    renderAdMobRewarded()

  }, []);
 const renderAdMobRewarded= async () => {
    const testRewared = 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712';
    await AdMobRewarded.setAdUnitID(testRewared);
    await AdMobRewarded.requestAdAsync();
    await AdMobRewarded.showAdAsync();
  };

return(...);

};
```

Comment: Can you share some explanations how this could fix the issue.